# Bind Greenlock to specific ip address?

Tags: node.js, greenlock

I've got greenlock express running well in node.js on my Windows server.  However, I've added some more IP addresses to the server and find that node.js and greenlock are listening to port 443 on 0.0.0.0, thereby tieing up all the IP addresses.

How do I tell greenlock to listen to port 443 only on one specific IP address?

Is there any configuration value that I can add to this?

```
var greenlock = require('greenlock-express')
    .init({ 
        packageRoot: __dirname,
        maintainerEmail: "....",
        configDir: './greenlock.d',
        cluster: false
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

That's in the examples folder https://git.rootprojects.org/root/greenlock-express.js/src/branch/master/examples/https/server.js

That's the folder you need to be looking at for more advanced uses.

```js
"use strict";

// The WRONG way:
//var https = require('https');
//var httpsServer = https.createServer(tlsOptions, app);
//
// Why is that wrong?
// Greenlock needs to change some low-level http and https options.
// Use glx.httpsServer(tlsOptions, app) instead.

//require("greenlock-express")
require("../../")
    .init({
        packageRoot: __dirname,
        configDir: "./greenlock.d",

        maintainerEmail: "jon@example.com",
        cluster: false
    })
    .ready(httpsWorker);

function httpsWorker(glx) {
    //
    // HTTPS 1.1 is the default
    // (HTTP2 would be the default but... https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3388)
    //

    // Get the raw https server:
    var httpsServer = glx.httpsServer(null, function(req, res) {
        res.end("Hello, Encrypted World!");
    });

    httpsServer.listen(443, "0.0.0.0", function() {
        console.info("Listening on ", httpsServer.address());
    });

    // Note:
    // You must ALSO listen on port 80 for ACME HTTP-01 Challenges
    // (the ACME and http->https middleware are loaded by glx.httpServer)
    var httpServer = glx.httpServer();

    httpServer.listen(80, "0.0.0.0", function() {
        console.info("Listening on ", httpServer.address());
    });
}
```

I saw that you left an issue (yesterday?), but I forgot to respond.

Comment: When I do this, I now get this error: `Error [ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN] [ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN]: Listen method has been called more than once without closing.`

Comment: Sounds like a stale binding (or another service listening on the same address and port). Try rebooting and use `netstat` and `systemctl` to make sure nothing else is running that uses those.

Comment: I get the following error `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string`. But i have no idea which `path` it is talking about